# Counting the number of duplicates with nested loops. How to escape from comparing two chars with the same index

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

Function that will return the count of distinct case-insensitive alphabetic characters and numeric digits that occur more than once in the input string.

"abcde" -> 0 # no characters repeats more than once

"indivisibility" -> 1 # 'i' occurs six times
rs twice

The problem is that each iteration loops meet on the same char and compare it. How can I avoid it?

```
function duplicateCount(text){
  var texT = text.toLowerCase();
var count = 0;
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < texT.length; i++ ){
      var char = texT[i];
      if(count > 1){
            total = total + 1;
      }
  
      for ( var j = 0; j < texT.length; j++){
          var char2 = texT[j];
          if(char === char2){
              count = count + 1;
          }
    
          
      }
      
  }
     return total;
  
}
duplicateCount('kBHhJkj8l8');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function duplicateCount(text){
  var texT = text.toLowerCase();
  const obj = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < texT.length; i++ ){
      if(obj[texT[i]]) {
        obj[texT[i]] += 1;
      }
      else {
        obj[texT[i]] = 1;
      }
  }
  let total = 0;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if(obj[key] != 1){
      total += 1;
    }
  })
  return total;
}
console.log(duplicateCount('kBHhJkj8l8'));
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot!!

Comment: Happy to help :) Hope it worked for you. in case you can upvote/accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash to keep track of the visited chars, and skip the comparison if you already have a duplicate char (at least 2):

```js
function duplicateCount(text){

  text = text.toLowerCase();

  const occurrences = {};

  for (let char of text) {
    if (occurrences[char] === 2) continue; // skip comparison
    occurrences[char] = ~~ occurrences[char] + 1;
  }

  return Object.values(occurrences)
    .filter((occurrence) => occurrence > 1)
    .length;
}

console.log(duplicateCount('kBHhJkj8l88888'));
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a beginner.. This solution is blowing my mind)). Going through it and trying my best to understand. ))